# NO USB devices show in windows 8.1 device manager

Tags: windows, usb

Whatever I plug into my USB ports will get power and will charge but will not connect to the computer. I have restarted the computer several times, I re-installed the chipset drivers and still even a USB HDD will not show up under the device manager, not even as an unknown device.

I believe this happened because I switched android adb to listen on tcpip rather than USB as this is when the USB ports stopped working. I have set it back to USB but that hasn't seemed to correct the issue.

It seems to me that ADB has shut off detection of devices through USB and I am out of ideas and can't find anything useful online. I would prefer not to have to reinstall windows unless I really have to but it is looking like that is exactly what I am going to have to do. I am using windows 8.1.

Thanks

Comment: What kind of device?

Comment: You say no USB devices show, but do you see the USB host controller in the Device Manager?

Answer (score 1):

There's about a dozen variations or more of this question across Stack Overflow. All with accepted answers that are very unique. So search around, you might get lucky.

I'm running Win 8.1 and have had my Nexus, Kindle, and HTC device running fine.

Do the following:

1. Reboot. I'm sure you've done this several times already.
2. With your device plugged in.  From Windows Control Panel, select Device Manager, identify your device in the tree.  Right click on it and select "Properties". From the "Driver" tab of the Properties dialog, select Uninstall.
3. Unplug your device from USB.
4. Re-install the device driver.  You didn't mention what device or where you got the original driver from.  Start with that.  For some of my devices, the Google USB Driver available from the SDK Manager works.  Not it's not sufficient to just download the Google USB Driver from the SDK Manager. You actually have to install it.  Go to c:\your_adt_directory\sdk\extras\google\usb_driver.  Right click on android_winusb.inf and select "Install".
5. Plug your device back in.  Wait for the usual Windows beeps to indicate a new device is plugged in and let the driver finish installing.
6. From the command prompt, kill any running adb service by typing `adb kill-server`
7. Type `adb shell`. If you get a shell prompt you are good to go.
8. Still having trouble. Unplug the device and plug it back into USB one more time. (I have to do this with my HTC when it's installed on a new PC).  Repeat step 6 and 7.

When in doubt - try all the above from a different USB port.

Comment: I know there are a ton of questions and acceptable answers for issues similar to mine, however I am yet to find one where as I stated in my original question no USB devices will show up in the device manager at all. I have tried multiple devices in all USB ports including a USB external hard drive, NEXUS 7, Galaxy S2, etc. But regardless of the device NOTHING shows up in the device manager. It is almost like detection of USB devices is shut off in windows.

Comment: so re-installing device drivers for the device is pointless since the device will show that is is being charged/getting power from the USB port but windows doesn't see the device at all. I have also already re-installed the chipset drivers from my laptop manufacturers website which made no difference.